# Does the internal browser phonegap uses update whenever the native browser updates on android?

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, browser, native

I am experiencing a bug in our application and noticed that the bug is only happening in Chrome and the Native browser and not Firefox. Once I found this bug, I also noticed our phonegap application was now experiencing the same bug. I know that phonegap internally uses the native browser that android comes with; does this mean whenever the native browser is updated, the browser phonegap uses is updated as well? I guess I thought that it internally packaged its own version of the native browser and only through updating phonegap did this browser get updated. Is this not the case?

Thanks!

Comment: The WebView may be updated when the OS is updated. As a major milestone, as of Android 4.4, the WebView has been updated to be based on Chromium, rather than "Android Browser" (which is in turn webkit based), which means you might see different behavior. Most notably, file-uploads are broken universally in Android 4.4 WebView.

Comment: @323go Yeah, I did some further research and found that this is the cause of our issue. The native webview is now Chromium based, and this bug here is what is causing an internal issue we are having.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639

Since phonegap is directly tied to the native webview, this Chromium bug is now a bug in our Phonegap application.

Comment: @323go also thanks for your helpful input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my inital guess is correct. Phonegap is using the Webview Class, which starting with Android 4.4 is now using the Chromium Engine instead of Webkit. This change is the root of my issue.

For those interested, my keyup and keydown events were not receiving the proper keycodes, which is a known bug in the Chromium engine:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639